# High Memory server, apache not using All ram

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd, litespeed

I have 64G Memory, 12coreX3CPU , SATA HDD...
But memory using  %5 ??
How to increase this limit?

htop
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STqtm.png

top -c
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpjAx.png

```
    [root@ns228430 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64461      13329      51131          0       1444       4334
-/+ buffers/cache:       7550      56910
Swap:         1025          0       1025
[root@ns228430 ~]#

[root@ns228430 ~]# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
vm.swappiness = 60
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 240
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 28800
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 256000
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 2
net.core.somaxconn = 262144
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
```

---

My current Apache prefork settings

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit         4450
    MaxClients         4450
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

after reboot, ram usage dropped.
I now installed LiteSpeed but no change was not:(
http://i.hizliresim.com/PYPgXb.png

Comment: Why would you think apache *needs* more ram?

Comment: Get more traffic to your website?

Comment: Please state why you think that you have a problem. Also, use the edit button to provide more information, not the answer field or comments.

Comment: database is the only one who needs more ram, and takes it instantly, apache will take ram only if there is any traffic

Comment: After a certain time, to apache crashed. (Httpd proc working but not responding + Not get error log)...Apache 2.2 updated to 2.4 version.(Ram use the same, but do not crash now..I'm waiting for the results of the apache 2.4)

Comment: Total : 62 Used: 50 Free: 12 Solution: Update apache to new version (2.2 to 2.4.10)

Answer (score 1):

Apache uses as much RAM as it needs to based on your prefork settings (assuming you're using the prefork MPM, which you almost certainly are). You'll want to research each of the following options to see how much your hardware can handle:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  StartServers         4
  MinSpareServers      3
  MaxSpareServers      10
  ServerLimit          256
  MaxClients           256
  MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

Furthermore, this is all contingent on your instance of Apache actually needing those resources. With 64GBs of RAM, unless you're handling thousands and thousands of concurrent users, you won't be using that much RAM for Apache alone.